# Laravel Eloquent function with() is the same as join?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I used to think that when i am using with() function with relations it is the same what join is, so for example if I have User::with('shop') it will join this second table and it is one query. Now when I turned on sql debug log I can see it is not join action, just another query without bindings.

My question is: is joining table on my own is faster than using with() ?

Comment: This question / similar questions have been asked twenty million and 5 times. Here's a start: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577188/3532758

Comment: `with` does a separate query. The reason why this is usually faster than a join refer to the link above

Answer (score 3):

`$user->join('shop', 'users.id', '=', 'shop.user_id')` generates the query below:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `shop`
   ON `users`.`id` = `shop`.`user_id`
WHERE `first_name` LIKE '%a%'
```

`User::with('shop')` this eager loading outputs the query below:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM `shop`
    WHERE `users`.`id` = `shop`.`user_id` AND
        `first_name` LIKE '%a%'
)
```

##### Comparison of select operation average response time between Eloquent ORM and Raw SQL

###### Eloquent ORM average response time

| Joins | Average (ms) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 162,2 |
| 3 | 1002,7 |
| 4 | 1540,0 |

###### Raw SQL average response time

| Joins | Average (ms) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 116,4 |
| 3 | 130,6 |
| 4 | 155,2 |

So, **join query** is faster than using `with('shop')`

Answer (score -1):

Yes join works faster because with the with operator eager loading is used for the eloquent relationships. Eloquent model uses toArray() which merges own attributes and relationships in one representation, thus it performs worst.

To double check:

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
$builtQuery->get()
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```